# KSQL websocket endpoints

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I want to use continuous queries to KSQL Server using web socket queries.
I heard that the KSQL CLI and Control Center interact with KSQL Server using web socket requests, but I did not find any information on using web sockets in the KSQL REST API reference. How to configure and use this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websockets is not a supported API, and not documented.

I guess you could run Confluent Control Center yourself and sniff its behaviour, but there'd be no guarantee that the API wouldn't change.